# Java Sample code for Authentication with Ping Federate and SalesForce

Tags: java, salesforce, pingfederate

I'm new to SAML, SalesForce and PingFederate and have a need for integrating a Java based server with SalesForce and PingFederate using SAML assertions.  Essentially what I need is to be able to do is to allow a SalesForce authenticated user to use the Java based server without having to re-enter user/pass info when the  directed to the Java server from SalesForce.  In turn, changes made from the Java server will need to be pushed back to SalesForce as well.

I've been trying to find Java code to handle authentication that I can incorporate with the Java based server, but I find bits and pieces here and there, but not a complete solution.

Are there any good Java sample code for authenticating against SalesForce with PingFederate using SAML?

TIA

Comment: Can you elaborate on the following statement of yours? "In turn, changes made from the Java server will need to be pushed back to SalesForce as well." Per my understanding you want to write data to Salesforce, which would be a separate topic that is not part of the Authentication Dance.

Comment: I have this requirement as well. I have a Java Springbok application and I would like to use Ping Federate authentication for this app. I am not able to find any sample code for this (using a Java SDK to be used by such Java applications)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things you need to clarify first, the solution would follow.

- Who's going to be the Identity Provider, Salesforce or PingFederate?
- Is the Java Application going to be a standalone SAML 2.0 Service Provider or directly integrated with PingFederate, which takes care of federation?

---

Salesforce as IdP

- Either configure a SAML 2.0 Connection between the Salesforce IdP and PingFederate as the SP. ([Salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_about.htm), [PingFederate doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/concept_managingIdpConnections.html))
- Or use the Salesforce Cloud Identity Connector for PingFederate, which provides an IdP adapter. ([doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/SFCIC))

Salesforce as SP:

- Either configure a SAML 2.0 Connection between PingFederate as the IdP and Salesforce as the SP. ([PingFederate doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/adminGuide/concept/managingSpConnections.html), [Salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml_setting_up.htm))
- Or use the Salesforce Connector for PingFederate, which simplifies the configuration. ([doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/SFC51/))

Java App as standalone SP:

- Use one of the many SAML 2.0 Libraries for Java, then configure for PingFederate as the IdP.

Java App integrated to PingFederate:

- Also called the "last-mile integration", PingFederate has several Integration Kits available which can be used for this purpose, the Java IK and the Agentless (or RefID) IK being the two coming to mind. Both of these include Sample Applications which can be leveraged. ([Java IK doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/JIK25/), [Agentless IK doc](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/))

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, there are three subsystems, mainly (1) PingFederate as the Identity Provider (IdP), (2) Salesforce as an application, and (3) your Java based server application. Single sign-on (SSO) occurs via PingFederate issuing SAML tokens to each application.  Once a authenticated session occurs by accessing one of the two applications, the second will not be challanged to re-authenticate granted SSO p[olicy has not expired.

There are two SAML connections here, mainly the Salesforce connection and the connection to your Java Application. There are many tutorials on the internet to configure the Salesforce-PingFederate SAML connection.  Your question  asking "how to setup a connection to your Java based application from PingFederate". There are a couple of options here using PingFederate.  I recommend you download the Agentless (also known as reference ID) integration kit and the Java Integration Kit.  Both of these integration kits allow "last mile" integration to your Java based server application.  Both of the kits have documentation and samples.  My preference is the Agentless integration kit since it uses REST API and does not require any libraries being compiled into your application.